# Reinstall Bluetooth elementary OS

Tags: bluetooth

From a lot of time my bluetooth does not work on elementary OS. On Ubuntu is okay, in Windows also, but elementary OS bluetooth icon is always gray even if I switch it on from wingpanel and cannot discover any device. So, I have tried a lot of 'solutions' found by google and finally manage to found devices using *blueman*, but still cannot connect to audio devices or make file exchanges.

Does anyone know which commands I can use in order to reinstall the elementary OS bluetooth packages instead of installing some another apps like *blueman*, which do not work good as well?

the output of `rfkill list` command is

`1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no`

Comment: Very Very Very good !!!! thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, unblocking solution found [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688090/cannot-unblock-soft-blocked-bluetooth)

`rfkill unblock bluetooth
systemctl enable bluetooth.service
systemctl start bluetooth.service`

afterwords the solution for the bluetooth audio from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634382/bluetooth-speaker-pairs-but-wont-connect)

`sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`

Then try deleting/removing the device from bluetooth devices and pair it again.

..and I have bluetooth audio working.

Answer (score 2):

So, I tried a lot of different ways of doing this.

First, make sure your user is in the bluetooth group.

```
$ sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a <your_username>
```

Restarting your bluetooth service (and making sure it is enabled to start on boot) should be the next thing you try after checking the rfkill status - see other answers here on that.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart bluetooth    
$ sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bluetooth
```

Finally, some bluetooth controllers need to first remove the definition - perhaps you dual boot, or have a previous install - and then add the definition back in.

I needed to use the bluetoothctl command line tool to remove and add back, perhaps because I needed to enter a PIN for my bluetooth-enabled amplifier. Like so...

```
$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 00:1B:63:43:9B:E6 imac [default]
[NEW] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 STR-DH190
Agent registered
[STR-DH190]# help
Menu main:
Available commands:
-------------------
advertise                                         Advertise Options Submenu
scan                                              Scan Options Submenu
gatt                                              Generic Attribute Submenu
list                                              List available controllers
show [ctrl]                                       Controller information
select <ctrl>                                     Select default controller
devices                                           List available devices
paired-devices                                    List paired devices
system-alias <name>                               Set controller alias
reset-alias                                       Reset controller alias
power <on/off>                                    Set controller power
pairable <on/off>                                 Set controller pairable mode
discoverable <on/off>                             Set controller discoverable mode
agent <on/off/capability>                         Enable/disable agent with given capability
default-agent                                     Set agent as the default one
advertise <on/off/type>                           Enable/disable advertising with given type
set-alias <alias>                                 Set device alias
scan <on/off>                                     Scan for devices
info [dev]                                        Device information
pair [dev]                                        Pair with device
trust [dev]                                       Trust device
untrust [dev]                                     Untrust device
block [dev]                                       Block device
unblock [dev]                                     Unblock device
remove <dev>                                      Remove device
connect <dev>                                     Connect device
disconnect [dev]                                  Disconnect device
menu <name>                                       Select submenu
version                                           Display version
quit                                              Quit program
exit                                              Quit program
help                                              Display help about this program
[STR-DH190]# remove 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27
[CHG] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 ServicesResolved: no
Device has been removed
[CHG] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 Connected: no
[DEL] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 STR-DH190
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 00:1B:63:43:9B:E6 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 STR-DH190
[bluetooth]# pair 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27
Attempting to pair with 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27
[CHG] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 Connected: yes
Request PIN code
[STR-1m[agent] Enter PIN code: xxxx
[CHG] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 Modalias: bluetooth:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[CHG] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 RSSI: -56
[CHG] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 RSSI: -48
[bluetooth]# trust 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27
[CHG] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 Trusted: yes
Changing 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# list
Controller 00:1B:63:43:9B:E6 imac [default]
[CHG] Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 RSSI: -56
[bluetooth]# system-alias big-imac
Changing big-imac succeeded
[CHG] Controller 00:1B:63:43:9B:E6 Alias: big-imac
[bluetooth]# info 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27
Device 00:F4:8D:2C:BD:27 (public)
    Name: STR-DH190
    Alias: STR-DH190
    Class: 0x00240414
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: yes
    UUID: Serial Port               (...)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (...)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (...)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (...)
    UUID: PnP Information           (...)
    Modalias: bluetooth:xxxxxxxxxxxx
    RSSI: -56
[bluetooth]# exit
Agent unregistered
[DEL] Controller 00:1B:63:43:9B:E6 big-imac [default]
phil@imac:~$
```

You can now use the widget in the toolbar to control the connection(s) you just created, and the Bluetooth menu in System Settings works as expected.

Happy bluetoothing!

Thanks