# Bluetooth not working and not showing up in settings

Tags: bluetooth

After I installed elementary os Bluetooth stopped appering as an option in my laptop.

Comment: I had this problem too, installing blueman are don't helps

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Bluetooth first is it disabled or not installed.

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth
```

and look the status, on my laptop, it was disabled because I don't use it.

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

To activate the bluetooth service do the command bellow.

```
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

Or if it doesn't help you. You can visit previous thread similar like these
[Visit.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15329/reinstall-bluetooth-elementary-os)